# Feynman diagram - direction of arrows

Tags: particle-physics, conventions, notation, feynman-diagrams, antimatter

http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1f/Feynmann_Diagram_Gluon_Radiation.svg

Why is the arrow of the positron not upwards?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The arrow is related to the flow of charge, not the direction of motion.  So for antimatter they go the opposite way.

Or as some are fond of saying, the positron is like an electron moving backwards in time.

Comment: Thanks! But moving backwards in time? This is a joke right?

Comment: Not a joke at all. This isn't a joke either: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-electron_universe

Comment: @Keenan: ''moving backward in time'' is a relic from the times of the dirac sea. But in quantum field theory, all particles move forward in time (i.e., the momentum vector has a positive 0-component).