# How does electron gets negative charge and proton gets positive charge?

Tags: charge, mass-energy, elementary-particles

I researched much in physics but I still do not know how does electron gets negative charge and proton gets positive charge? What is the source of this charge and energy?

How can this particles maintain their same energy state for infinite time?

why doesn't they lose all their energy in form of electromagnetic radiation and be non-existent?

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/178710/ See this, answers a part of your question.

Comment: This has been asked & answered before, but as I am using the mobile app, my ability to find it is hindered somewhat.

Answer (score 0):

It is because they only lose there energy when accelerating. A moving electron or proton with a constant velocity won't emit EM radiation. The electronmagnetic radiation only takes away the aceleration, slowly the proton or electron down to a constant velocity. The reason they have charges is much more complicated. For the proton example it is because protons are made up of particles called quarks. The charges of the quarks hat form the proton add up to the charge of the proton.

Answer (score 0):

See explanations on [Quarks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark) and Gell-Mann's [Quark Model.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark_model)