# Drawing Feynman diagram for positronium decay into 2 photons

Tags: particle-physics, photons, electrons, quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams

I am studying the annihilation processes and read that electron-positron annihilation releases 2 photons. I know that releasing 1 photon is not possible because it violates the conservation of $E$. But it can decay into more than two photons, such as three for positronium decay. I am a little confused with the terms.

Does positronium decay mean the same as electron-positron annihilation?

How can we draw Feynman diagrams for such a case where 2 particles release three identical particles and find the corresponding amplitude and energy?
Can anyone explain?

Comment: Pretty much like in [this PSE post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/17521/electron-positron-annihilation-feynman-diagram), but with another photon in the middle.

Comment: see the drawings here  https://www.sarthaks.com/454264/draw-feynman-diagrams-for-two-photon-annihilation-three-photon-annihilation-positronium